# TCL AES <-> C# AES - Tcl encrypted text is ASCII

Tags: c#, encoding, tcl, aes

I am new to TCL and need some help here.

I wrote a client/server application: The server is implemented in C# (.Net 4.51) the client in TCL 8.2.
The basic communication is working fine, now I need to encrypt the messages passed between client and server. Unfortunately, SSL is not an option since the client is out of my control and there is no SSL library installed.

I choose the TclLib (1.15) Aes implementation to do the encryption.

To check that the Aes is correctly set up at both sides I did the following test:

the IV is: "20140204_1231060"
The Key is :"QbPQiCOTmBzLgCc40ElxH2588jmRljmq"
My test data is "Hello World".

Each side is able to decrypt theire on encrypted data.

This is the TCL code:

```
proc ::orbylonCrypto::encrypt { keyData ivData clearText } {

  set clearText [::aes::Pad $clearText 16];

  set key [::aes::Init cbc $keyData $ivData];  
  set ciphertext [::aes::Encrypt $key $clearText];
  ::aes::Final $key

  return [::aes::Hex $ciphertext];

}

proc ::orbylonCrypto::decrypt { keyData ivData ciphertext } {

  set key [::aes::Init cbc $keyData $ivData];  
  set clearText [::aes::Decrypt $key [ binary format H* $ciphertext ]];
  ::aes::Final $key

  return [ string trimright $clearText \0 ];

}
...

  set clearText {Hello World};
  set iv "20140204_1231060"
  set key "QbPQiCOTmBzLgCc40ElxH2588jmRljmq"

  set encrypted [::orbylonCrypto::encrypt $key $iv $clearText];
  set decrypted [::orbylonCrypto::decrypt $key $iv $encrypted];
```

and gives me this value for "encrypted": 
"e9455ec1788f5431fd103694c235670f"

This is the C# Code::

```
public static string Encrypt(string clearText, string key, string iv)
{
  string encryptedString;
  var keyBytes = getValidatedKey(key);
  var ivBytes = getValidatedIV(iv);

  //byte[] clearTextBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(clearText);
  byte[] clearTextBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
  using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
  {
    initializeAes(encryptor, keyBytes, ivBytes);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
      using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
      {
        cs.Write(clearTextBytes, 0, clearTextBytes.Length);
        cs.Close();
      }
      encryptedString = bytesToHexString(ms.ToArray());
    }
  }
  return encryptedString;
}

public static string Decrypt(string encryptedText, string key, string iv)
{
  string encryptedString;
  var keyBytes = getValidatedKey(key);
  var ivBytes = getValidatedIV(iv);

  byte[] encryptedBytes = hexStringToByteArray(encryptedText);
  using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
  {
    initializeAes(encryptor, keyBytes, ivBytes);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
      using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
      {
        cs.Write(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
        cs.Close();
      }
      // encryptedString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
      encryptedString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
      encryptedString = encryptedString.TrimEnd('\0');
    }
  }
  return encryptedString;
}

private static void initializeAes(Aes aes, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] ivBytes)
{
  aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
  aes.BlockSize = 128;
  aes.KeySize = 256;
  aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

  aes.Key = keyBytes;
  aes.IV = ivBytes;
}

private static byte[] getValidatedIV(string iv)
{
  byte[] ivBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(iv);
  if (ivBytes.Length != 16)
  {
    throw new ArgumentException("The IV must have a length of 16 bytes.");
  }
  return ivBytes;
}

private static byte[] getValidatedKey(string key)
{
  byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
  if (keyBytes.Length != 32)
  {
    throw new ArgumentException("The Key must have a length of 32 bytes.");
  }
  return keyBytes;
}

...

string iv = "20140204_1231060";
string key = "QbPQiCOTmBzLgCc40ElxH2588jmRljmq";

string inClearText = "Hello World";

string encrypted = AesCryption.Encrypt(inClearText, key, iv);
string outClearText = AesCryption.Decrypt(encrypted, key, iv);
```

And gives me this value for "encrypted": 
"1d080b143641984d7623fce65c8a551853e2d9189413e9895f72065fde17e479"

The output of the C# version is twice as long.

If I convert the input data at the c# side to ASCII before doing the encryption, I have the exact same output and the TCL implementation is able to decrypt it.
My understanding is that TCL is unicode "aware", my not encrypted messages are passed between the client and server as plain text without any encoding problems.

I have no idea what is removing the encoding here. I have the feeling that the "::aes::Hex" which is implemented as

```
proc ::aes::Hex {data} {
    binary scan $data H* r
    return $r 
}
```

and

```
[ binary format H* $ciphertext ]
```

is the problem here. But I am not too sure about that.

Any help is much appreciate!

Comment: Tcl 8.2? That's _ancient_! A software version that I don't think has been current for 15 years…

Comment: But seriously, the Tcl version doesn't seem to matter in this case. The aes package behaves the same in 8.6.1 (though I can use a less annoying interface as well). I just can't figure out where the doubled information in the C# code is coming from; it shouldn't take that many bytes to encode that message! What is the value of `clearTextBytes` exactly?

Comment: Also, FWIW the Tcl code is validated against the test vectors in the AES standard itself. (Read the [tests](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/artifact/924471906286a5b1d51758ed52426a0e8de33aee) for yourself.) Whatever is going on, I'm not at all convinced that it is a Tcl problem.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Donal Fellow hint to have a look at my clearTextBytes, the problem is clear.
TCL uses not Unicode but UTF-8. So I need to convert the C# text to UTF8 before encrypting and back after decrypting:

```
byte[] clearTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearText);
```

and

```
decryptedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I tried that on the Tcl side and was still confused, but I'm happy it seems to have worked for you. Note that the equivalent operations on the Tcl side involve `encoding convertto` and `encoding convertfrom`; encryptions should properly be applied to the encoded forms.

Comment: @Donal Fellows: Thanks for the Tcl encoding tip.